# Fast listing files in a directory and all of its subdirectories

Tags: java, io, file-listing

I need to find all files in a directory and all of its subdirectories (except some).
Currently I'm using this method:

```
public  static Collection<File> listFiles(File directory,FilenameFilter filter,boolean recurse){
    Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();
    File[] entries = directory.listFiles();
    if(entries!=null){
        for (File entry : entries){
            if (filter == null || filter.accept(directory, entry.getName())){
                    files.add(entry);
            }

            if (recurse && entry.isDirectory()){
                    files.addAll(listFiles(entry, filter, recurse));
            }
        }
    }
    return files;
}
```

and using it like this:

```
        this.foundFiles=listFiles(new File(this.BaseDirectory), new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                boolean res=true;
                if(name.endsWith(".pdf")){
                    if(!dir.getPath().endsWith("done")){
                        if((workingFile!=null && (dir.getPath().equals(workingFile.getParent()) && name.equals(workingFile.getName())))){
                            res=false;
                        }else{
                            try {
                                ArrayList<String> AuthFolders = DB.getGroupAuthFoldersArray();
                                for(String folder:AuthFolders){
                                    if(dir.getPath().startsWith(BaseDirectory+File.separator+folder)){
                                        res=true;
                                        break;
                                    }else{
                                        res=false;
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(scanner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                res=false;
                            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(scanner.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                res=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        res=false;
                    }
                }else{
                    res=false;
                }
                return res;
            }
        }, true);
```

But this is too slow! I have about 3000 files in the directory and it takes 10-15 mins (!!) for this method to find them all.

How Can I do this fast?
I'm thinking about using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listfiles` method.  Is there a faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listfiles? Maybe its as fast as you need it. BTW: You query the database for every found pdf file? I would point at this as an performance killer.

Comment: 10-15 minutes? Where is it for so long? The profiler (or `-Xprof` JVM flag) is your best friend. Anyway, I'd give the Apache Commons `listfile()` method a shot, it is used extensively throughout the world.

Comment: why you not passing filter to listFiles method? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)

Comment: @flash: As I mentioned at the end of question. it is an option that i'm going to use it and want to know is there a faster method or not.

Comment: Listing is not the issue. Your problem is in DB lookup for each file.

Comment: @tigran: You're right! I thought it is a static method that only read a static array but it runs an sql query everytime! Thanks

Comment: `} catch (SQLException ex) {`  What is that doing in a class intended to do a ***directory listing?***  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: it is exactly the problem it's calling an sql for each file (!), problem fixed. thanks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)  I put an edited form of that comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
} catch (SQLException ex) {
```

This does not belong in a class intended to do a directory listing!

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Files.walkFileTree`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) in Java 7, which is faster than `listFiles` because it uses streaming. Read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) for more information.